# PclZip create empty directory in zip file

Tags: zip, pclzip

How can I create empty folde in zip file?

I can successfuly add files in zip, but fail to create folder.

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-pclzip.php');

$pclzip = new PclZip($upload_path1.$zipname);

$list = $pclzip->create('assets/');
if($list == 0){
    echo json_encode("ERROR : '".$pclzip->errorInfo(true)."'");
}
```

I get error:

```
"ERROR : 'PCLZIP_ERR_MISSING_FILE (-4) : File 'assets\/' does not exist'
```

I dont want to copy 'assets', I just want to create empty directory.

With zipArchive I would just use:

```
 $zip->addEmptyDir('assets');
```